# Unable to install Truffle - cli.bundled.js error

Tags: truffle, error, installation

I'm unable to install Truffle. After installing I try the commands
`Truffle unbox pet-shop` & `Truffle --version` and I always get the same error which is the inability to find cli.bundled.js.

I've looked everywhere for solutions and none of the solutions I've come across helped me. Below you can find the code for the installation and the cli.bundled.js error. Node.js is up to date and I also installed Git.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1526]

C:\Users\jrroo>npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated ipld-raw@6.0.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated cids@1.1.9: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-cbor@0.17.1: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-cbor and multiformats
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated @nodefactory/filsnap-adapter@0.2.2: Package is deprecated in favour of @chainsafe/filsnap-adapter
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated multibase@3.1.2: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-pb@0.20.0: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-pb and multiformats
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@3.2.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.20.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\@trufflesuite\bigint-buffer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\jrroo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\jrroo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jrroo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\jrroo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:418:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jrroo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\@trufflesuite\bigint-buffer
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-22T19_19_56_979Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\jrroo>truffle unbox pet-shop
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jrroo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I also faced a similar issue at my end. On my windows machine.

- First, I had to install Python3. [Download Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
- And then `npm install -g truffle.`

After that, I was able to use truffle.

Note: Due to some configuration, I am still unable to access truffle on PowerShell. But on git bash and on cmd I was able to access it.

[image]

Comment: Yes that did it. I also had to use the command npm audit fix --force and got Truffle to work. Thanks a lot!